# How can I extract the font from the 'lux' theme in bootswatch and use it in my R Shiny app using bslib?

Tags: r, shiny, bslib

How do I extract a font from a bootswatch theme and use it in a R Shiny app?

I'm using the bslib library and trying to extract the font from the "lux" theme so I can use it with another theme.

I'm assuming it goes somewhere in the bs_add_variables function or base_font?

```
bs_add_variables(
    "font-family-base" = "monospace"
```

Answer (score 0):

The base font family can be set directly via the `base_font` argument of `bs_theme()`. Using the base font for the Lux theme which is `"Nunito Sans"`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_fixed(
  theme = bs_theme(
    version = 5,
    base_font = font_google("Nunito Sans"),
  ),
  h2("Hello world")
)
shinyApp(ui, function(...) {})
```

**EDIT** Replicating the look of the Lux theme requires more effort than just changing the base font, e.g. to replicate the look for the headings requires to set the font size and weight which could be achieved via BS variables and to add some additional CSS using `bs_add_rules`. But it's still not perfect.

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_fixed(
  theme = bs_theme(
    version = 5,
    base_font = font_google("Nunito Sans"),
    "h1-font-size" = "2rem",
    "headings-font-weight" = "600 !default"
  ) |> 
    bs_add_rules("h1 { text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 3px;}"),
  h1("Replicating the \"Lux\""),
  h1("Hello world")
)

shinyApp(ui, function(...) {})
```

[image]

For comparison, using the Lux theme directly:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_fixed(
  theme = bs_theme(
    version = 5,
    bootswatch = "lux"
  ),
  h1("Using bootswatch = \"lux\""),
  h1("Hello World")
)

shinyApp(ui, function(...) {})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but when I use bslib::bs_theme(version = 5, bootswatch = "lux") the font looks different than "Nunito Sans." Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: When running via `reprex` we lost the correct font. I just made an edit which hopefully shows that `"Nunito Sans"` is the font used by Lux which you could also check from the developer tools of your browser or by having as look at the SCSS files of the Lux theme (https://bootswatch.com/lux/). However, getting the Lux look requires some more effort than just changing the base font.

Comment: Thank you for this. It's very close!